# workout daily or not?

Tags: workout, rest

I am 42 and have been working out for 2 months
my primary goal is to bulk up I am working out every day, and every day I do chest, bi, back, shoulders, I spend between an hour and a half to 2 hours in the gym

my question is,
what kind of diet and workout out plan should I use to bulk up my 42-year-old body because I have not seen the results I would like to see for the amount of work I have put in the last 2 months?

Comment: First of all, do you use hormones or you train naturally?

Comment: I'm not an expert at all but if you train naturally - when you train evey single day your body would be in constant stress which is not good for muscle grown. Especially when you in your forties and your testosterone level is lower then 20 or 10 years ago

Comment: No you shouldn't train the same muscles everyday. They need to recover in order to grow, if you train them everyday you're not giving them the time they need to recover.

Comment: I would agree with @DanilGholtsman on your testosterone levels being lower now then they were in you 20's and early 30's. You should take some Testosterone booster for that. Your body for sure needs rest in order to grow, you should practice muscle confusion also. One thing you are missing in your question is your diet. You should be asking what kind of diet and workout out plan should I use to bulk up my 42-year-old body because I have not seen the results I would like to see for the amount of work I have put in the last 2 months.

Comment: I dont use any hormones, i want to stay away from these things as much as possible. although I just yesterday I started taking protine and creatine. no special food diet, I eat normally.. eat tune, pizza, cheese, pepsi, meat, etc.

Comment: You need to fix your diet man. At 43 and eating like a 20 year old will probably do you more harm than good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First and Foremost

> every day I do chest, bi, back, shoulders

I noticed that you didn't mention **legs** in your exercise regime.

Your legs are comprised of the largest muscles (muscle-groups) in your body. Disregarding them is at your great detriment. Moreover if your interested in increasing your testosterone levels naturally, it's well known that *training legs brings the biggest increase to testosterone*.

Considering that testosterone is the primary hormone in muscle growth, it's time to integrate those leg exercises into your workouts.

Also no abs and triceps exercises are mentioned...

> I am 42 and have been working out for 2 months my primary goal is to bulk up
> I am working out every day

Bulking up (training for hypertrophy) requires rest. Even if you don't feel sore your muscles still need time to fully recover (and Grow!). I would argue that if you can train the same muscle groups everyday at the same intensity, then your are not training for hypertrophy. You're also not training with your utmost intensity.

> I spend between an hour and a half to 2 hours in the gym

It's not about the time, it's about the **Intensity**. Quality over quantity.
Take a shot of espresso if your working out when your tired, blast some pumping music and give it your all. Yell a bit of you need to (at your own discretion). Those guys (or girls) who are shouting at the gym are annoying, but they are (generally) putting some serious intensity into their workouts.

---

### My Recommendation

#### Workout 3 days a week

Each day full body - **Include Legs!** (Squats and Lunges are your new best friends)

Make it *INTENSE*

Take a fourth day for cardio

#### Change your Diet

Bulking doesn't mean your free to eat what you want, it doesn't go straight to your muscles (despite what the "bro-scientists" in your gym might tell you).

Stay away from fatty high carb foods (like Pizza), and sugar (no more Pepsi).

If you don't want to go to a nutritionist, check out the slow-carb-diet.

(Any considerable change in workout routine or diet should be discussed with your healthcare provider- or a certified nutritionist/Personal Trainer).